# private func vs final private func vs private final func in final class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `final` UIViewController class to not be inherited. Also I would like to declare a function inside. About that, I am a bit confused which function declaration of the followings serves better performance?

1. private func test()
2. final private func test()
3. private final func test()

To the best of my knowledge, `final` class would not allow to inherit an inner class to override any of those private methods. So, **`1`** and **`3`** would have **same** performance, since the compiler will not find any overridden declarations and will treat them as also `final`.

However, in option **`2`**, `final` precedes `private`, so compiler will know that no overridden can occur and it reduce dynamic dispatch at runtime and serves **best** performance

Does that sound correct? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If your class is final, than none of your functions can be overridden too, so final is redundant here.

Comment: Order or `final` and `private` (or `static` and `private`) doesn't matter.

Comment: As an aside, we don’t generally declare UIKit subclasses as `final`. First, all of the base class methods will be dynamically dispatched regardless, so the optimization benefits are limited. Second, we don’t randomly sacrifice inheritance behaviors for performance reasons unless it is really essential to do so (i.e., Knuth’s 3% situation, where you benchmarked the difference and found it was critical to optimize). Third, anything so computationally intensive that warranted static dispatch optimization is likely something that really doesn’t belong in the view controller, anyway.